# How to replace a given coordinate in a matrix with a given letter in prolog

Tags: prolog

I'm new to Prolog and I'm trying to program a predicate where a matrix such as
M = [[_, _, a, *], [*, _, _, *], [a, a, a, a], [*, _, a, _]],
a letter and a coordinate are given and I need to replace that coordinate with the letter.

This is what I have so far, however when it reaches replaceRow in replace it fails. I'm sure there's a simpler way to do this, I would really appreciate some help! Thank you in advance.

````
insert(Matrix, Letter, (L, C)):-
    insert(Matrix, Letter, (L, C), []).

insert(Matrix, Letter, (L, C), NewMatrix):-
    replace(Matrix, L, C, Letter, NewMatrix).

replace(Matrix, L, C, Letter, NewMatrix):-
    replace(Matrix, 1, L, C, Letter, [], NewMatrix).

replace([], _, _, _, _, NewMatrix, NewMatrix).

replace([H|T], L2, L, C, Letter, Aux, NewMatrix) :-
    (
        L2 < L;
        L2 > L
    ->    
        L2 is L2 + 1,
        append(Aux, [H], NewAux),
        replace([T], L2, L, C, Letter, NewAux, NewMatrix);

        L2 == L,
        replaceRow(H, C, Letter, Aux, NewMatrix),
        replace([T], L2, L, C, Letter, Aux, NewMatrix)
    ).    

replaceRow(Matrix, C, Letter, Aux, NewMatrix) :-
    replaceRow(Matrix, 1 , C, Letter, Aux, NewMatrix).

replaceRow([], _, _, _, NewMatrix, NewMatrix) :- !.

replaceRow([H | T], C2 , C, Letter, Aux, NewMatrix) :-
    (
        C2 < C;
        C2 > C
    ->    
        NewC is C2 + 1,
        append(Aux, [H], NewAux),
        replaceRow(T, NewC, C, Letter, NewAux, NewMatrix);

        C2 == C,
        NewC is C2 + 1,
        append(Aux, [Letter], NewAux),
        replaceRow(T, NewC, C, Letter, NewAux, NewMatrix)
    ).    

      ```
````

Comment: Do you mean *instantiate* as in https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=nth1/3 , or *replace* as in `replace_nth0` shown at https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=nth0/4 ?

Comment: @brebs I mean to update nth element and then reinsert. Something like replace_nth1 (element is 1-based).

Answer (score 1):

The swi-prolog predicate [nth1/4](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=nth1/4) can be used to remove or to insert an element into a list:

```
?- nth1(2, [a,b,c], _, List). % remove
List = [a, c].

?- nth1(2, List, b, [a,c]).   % insert
List = [a, b, c].
```

Thus, to replace the element in position (`I`,`J`) of a matrix, you can define (supposing 1-based positions):

```
replace(I, J, Matrix, Element, NewMatrix) :-
    nth1(I, Matrix, Row, RestOfMatrix),
    nth1(J, Row, _, RestOfRow),               % the removed element does not matter!
    nth1(J, NewRow, Element, RestOfRow),
    nth1(I, NewMatrix, NewRow, RestOfMatrix).
```

Examples:

```
?- replace(2, 3, [[a, b, c], [d, e, f], [g, h, i]], x, New).
New = [[a, b, c], [d, e, x], [g, h, i]].

?- replace(I, J, [[A, B], [C, D]], X, New).
I = J, J = 1,
New = [[X, B], [C, D]] ;
I = 1,
J = 2,
New = [[A, X], [C, D]] ;
I = 2,
J = 1,
New = [[A, B], [X, D]] ;
I = J, J = 2,
New = [[A, B], [C, X]] ;
false.
```

Answer (score -1):

To replace an element in a list:

```
nth1_replace(I, NewItem, List, OldItem, NewList) :-
    % Add start index
    nth1_replace_(List, 1, I, NewItem, OldItem, NewList).

nth1_replace_(List, U, I, NewItem, OldItem, R) :-
    % Cut, to avoid unwanted choicepoint
    (   I == U
    ->  !
    ;   I = U
    ),
    % Unify *after* the cut
    List = [OldItem|List0],
    R = [NewItem|List0].
nth1_replace_([H|T], U, I, NewItem, OldItem, [H|LU]) :-
    % Compare, if possible
    (   var(I)
    ->  true
    ;   I > U
    ),
    U1 is U + 1,
    nth1_replace_(T, U1, I, NewItem, OldItem, LU).
```

Results in swi-prolog:

```
% General query
?- nth1_replace(I, E, L, Old, NewL).
I = 1,
L = [Old|_A],
NewL = [E|_A] ;
I = 2,
L = [_A, Old|_B],
NewL = [_A, E|_B] ;
I = 3,
L = [_A, _B, Old|_C],
NewL = [_A, _B, E|_C] ;

% Deterministic
?- nth1_replace(3, r, [a,b,c,d,e,f], Old, NewL).
Old = c,
NewL = [a, b, r, d, e, f].
```

As a hint: for a matrix, you'll want to call `nth1_replace` *twice*.

Comment: This style is lengthier than using `append`, but demonstrates the low-level flexibility that is sometimes useful.

Answer (score -1):

To replace an element by index, you could use length/2 and append/3 like this:

```
replace_nth1(List, N, Old, New, Replaced) :-
    length([_|Prefix], N),
    append(Prefix, [Old|Rest], List),
    append(Prefix, [New|Rest], Replaced).
```

With this definition you get:

```
?- replace_nth1([a,b], 0, Old, x, Replaced).
false.

?- replace_nth1([a,b], 1, Old, x, Replaced).
Old = a,
Replaced = [x, b].

?- replace_nth1([a,b], 2, Old, x, Replaced).
Old = b,
Replaced = [a, x].

?- replace_nth1([a,b], 3, Old, x, Replaced).
false.
```

Note that this can loop if you leave the second argument (the index) as a variable:

```
?- replace_nth1([a,b], N, Old, x, Replaced).
N = 1,
Old = a,
Replaced = [x, b] ;
N = 2,
Old = b,
Replaced = [a, x] ;
% does not terminate
```

If you are planning to use it like this, you might need to constraint the index using the length of the input list:

```
replace_nth1(List, N, Old, New, Replaced) :-
    length(List, M),
    between(1, M, N),
    length([_|Prefix], N),
    append(Prefix, [Old|Rest], List),
    append(Prefix, [New|Rest], Replaced).
```

This correctly terminates for the query above, and enumerates solutions with the most general query:

```
?- replace_nth1([a,b], N, Old, x, Replaced).
N = 1,
Old = a,
Replaced = [x, b] ;
N = 2,
Old = b,
Replaced = [a, x].

?- replace_nth1(L, N, Old, New, R).
L = [Old],
N = 1,
R = [New] ;
L = [Old, _A],
N = 1,
R = [New, _A] ;
L = [_A, Old],
N = 2,
R = [_A, New] ;
L = [Old, _A, _B],
N = 1,
R = [New, _A, _B] ;
% and so on
```

You would have to do this twice, nested, for a matrix.